# Student's t-distribution

Tags: excel, t-distribution

I have two functions that provide an implementation of the t-distribution.

A webpage with a [Javascript algorithm](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/distributions/tDist.html). The algorithm takes two input **`x-value`** and `degrees_of_freedom`.

Excel's [TInv function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/tinv-HP005209317.aspx). The function also takes two inputs: **`probability`** and `degrees_of_freedom`.

Can you give me the relation between `probability` and `x-value`? I have doubts that the two methods calculates the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first takes a value on the `x-value` and degrees of freedom and reports the amount of probability to the left of the `x-value`. If you're familiar with calculus, this is the equivalent of taking the integral of the Student's *t* probability density function over the interval $(-\infty,x]$. If you're familiar with statistics, this is the Student's *t* cumulative density function evaluated at $x$ for some degrees of freedom.

The second does the inverse, taking some probability and returning the corresponding `x-value`. In statistics, this is called the quantile function.

So the *mathematical* relationship between the two is the same as for any function and its inverse, with the *substantive* knowledge that they also have probability-based interpretations and statistical applications.